# Firebase + gcloud storage + nodejs. Access Denied Error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, gcloud

I am trying to get the image `url` of my images from `firebase-storage` through `nodejs` `gcloud` library.

```
// Require gcloud
var gcloud = require('google-cloud');

// Enable Storage
var gcs = gcloud.storage({
    projectId: 'foo-project',
    keyFilename: 'path/to/key.json'
});

// Reference an existing bucket.
var bucket = gcs.bucket('foo-bucket.appspot.com');

var file = bucket.file('pictures/'+filename);

file.getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: '03-17-2025'
}, function(err, url) {
    log.error('GCLOUD', err) // null
    console.log(url) // im getting a url

});
```

The request replies a url but when I access it I get this error :

[image]

Also the url I get from `gcloud` is different from the url I get from `firebase`

From `gcloud` = `https://storage.googleapis.com/foo-bar.appspot.com/....`

From `firebase` = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mycure-v2.appspot.com/....`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your key.json. Make sure that all right.